# Is prophet Mohamed slave of Hamza forefathers?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad

Assalamu alaikum brother,

Is prophet Mohamed slave of Hamza forefathers? Why prophet Mohammad did not give any refute to Hamza words? I ask this question from below hadees. This hadees used by Christians against prophets Mohamed. Pls give me detailed answer.

> Narrated Husain bin 'Ali:
>   'Ali bin Abi Talib said: "I got a she-camel as my share of the war booty on the day (of the battle) of Badr, and Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) gave me another she-camel. I let both of them kneel at the door of one of the Ansar, intending to carry Idhkhir on them to sell it and use its price for my wedding banquet on marrying Fatima. A goldsmith from Bani Qainqa' was with me. Hamza bin 'Abdul-Muttalib was in that house drinking wine and a lady singer was reciting: "O Hamza! (Kill) the (two) fat old she camels (and serve them to your guests). So Hamza took his sword and went towards the two she-camels and cut off their humps and opened their flanks and took a part of their livers." (I said to Ibn Shihab, "Did he take part of the humps?" He replied, "He cut off their humps and carried them away.") `Ali further said, "When I saw that dreadful sight, I went to the Prophet (ﷺ) and told him the news. The Prophet (ﷺ) came out in the company of Zaid bin Haritha who was with him then, and I too went with them. He went to Hamza and spoke harshly to him. Hamza looked up and said, 'Aren't you only the slaves of my forefathers?' The Prophet (ﷺ) retreated and went out. This incident happened before the prohibition of drinking."
>   [Sahih al-Bukhari 2375](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/42/23)

Answer (score 1):

No, Muhammad ﷺ and Ali were nephews of Hamzah. Abdul-Muttalib was the father of Hamzah and the grandfather of Muhammad ﷺ and Ali. The Prophet was also the foster brother of Hamza through suckling.

What Hamza said was due to being intoxicated, and he was not refuted simply because it is futile to reason with a person while they are under influence.